# Numeric updown control for a UWP

Tags: uwp, numericupdown

Is there a numeric UpDown control that I can download that would work in a Universal Windows Application project?

I'm working on a Windows Store app, but I require a numeric UpDown control.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer this question, but for anyone looking for it there's the NumberBox control from WinUI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/number-box

Answer (score 2):

The WinRTXamlToolkit has one
https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit

Syncfusion controls have a numeric updown
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp

Telerik controls have a numeric updown
http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui